# AWS ElasticBean WSGIPath

Tags: amazon-web-services, wsgi, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a problem with the WSGIPath on AWS ElasticBean with Python. When I set :

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python
    option_name: WSGIPath
    value: wsgi.py
```

I get a `WSGIPath not found` error. When I simply rename my wsgi.py to application.py and change the WSGIPath configuration in my `.ebextensions/myconfig.config` to the following, everything works again.

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python
    option_name: WSGIPath
    value: application.py
```

Does anyone has any clue ?

Comment: There is a very helpful [issue in the boto repo](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/1087) about that. Seems it's overridden by .elasticbeanstalk/optionsettings.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend after deployment of your configuration file, with renamed wigipath to login to ec2, created by beanstalk and check wsgi.py really exists on server. Also you ca analyse server logs.

Comment: Don't forget to set key pair in environment settings in order have ability to connect by ssh.